# Zero friction wheel with magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to create a zero friction wheel using magnetism?

Comment: Zero friction is impossible, but very low friction can be achieved with magnetic bearings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_bearing

Comment: @CuriousOne Is zero friction impossible? I thought superfluids (such as Helium-4) flow without friction.

Comment: @theonlygusti: I was commenting on classical wheels. Whether you want to equate vortices in superfluids with classical rotation is up to you. In that sense one can certainly find similar phenomena in atomic and molecular physics, but they are usually considered stationary states. I admit that it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the technology is that of [magnetic bearings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_bearing) and comes in two forms. The first (see previous link) involves using electronics controlled magnetic levitation to prevent any contact between moving surfaces.

The second form uses a permanent magnet on a vertical shaft being supported magnetically by a similar magnet beneath it repelling it. Normal bearing are used to hold the shaft vertical, but all the load bearing is done by the frictionless field. This is a convenient technology for small vertical axis windmills for power generation.

Comment: Also used in turbopumps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the core issues relevant to your question are addressed here:

['What causes friction in magnetic bearings?'](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/what-causes-friction-in-magnetic-bearings)

The answer to your question would appear to be 'no'.

Comment: I agree, the question is/was quite theoretical and this does assist in answering a part of the broad question.